# Generic Azure Functions - Dynamic Connections

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I want to create and host a azure function that would take as input "azure-storage-account-name" and "path" and run some common logic and then return a list of processed blobs in *that* storage account at *that* path. I have 20 storage accounts and I was thinking to write single azure function in same subscription to have listing capability across all of them

I went through Azure function documentation couldn't figure out if this is even possible in current offering. Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: you also need a key to access the storage account unless you have made the folders public

Comment: Any particular reason why you would do that using a function instead of the Azure Blog Storage - List Blobs ? You could also do it in a Function, using the Azure Storage Library nuget package. Keep in mind that you'll need to store the storage connection strings for each storage account as well then.

Comment: When you say path ? you mean filename or every file in a container or in specific folder ?

Comment: Actually the idea is not only to list, but also delete the ones that are no longer needed. The logic is same for blobs across storage accounts. Hence, I need this functionality abstracted out so that its called for each storage account externally (say logic app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Imperative Bindings feature of Azure Functions. This is a sample code:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, Binder binder, TraceWriter log)
{
    var attributes = new Attribute[]
    {
        new StorageAccountAttribute("your account"),
        new BlobAttribute("your folder name")
    };

    var directory = await binder.BindAsync<CloudBlobDirectory>(attributes);
    log.Info(directory.ListBlobs().Count().ToString());

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the correct credentials, you can use the [Azure Storage REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/operations-on-the-account--blob-service-) to get a [list of containers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-containers2)